# Remix ETH doesn't show public variables when contract is deployed

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm trying to see the public variables in Remix's IDE and I don't see them after I hit deploy:

[image]

Comment: you most likely have to hit the debug button and check the variables from there

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I just figured it out, I have to compile my code every time before pressing Deploy,

Comment: You can also enable the "Auto compile" option in the "Solidity compiler" tab. As the name suggests, it compiles the contract automatically before each deploy, so you don't have to press the "Compile" button (or the keyboard shortcut) manually.